# Will Windows Phone 8 SDK run on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows-phone-8

How do you think? Could I use my Sony Vaio for development?

Answer (score 10):

You can modify the installation files to allow it to be installed on Windows 7.
Here are the modified setup files for WP8 SDK 9900:

1. Run `InstallWP8SDK.bat` to start the installation!
2. Download: http://www5.zippyshare.com/v/67777536/file.html

Have fun developing on the good old Windows 7.

Comment: How does this work, and what does this do?

I just attempted running the batch script and it failed.

Comment: Please write in steps how to install it. this setup failed :-(

Answer (score 8):

No, the WP8 SDK will only run on Windows 8. See the following reference:

http://www.wpcentral.com/windows-phone-8-sdk-preview-release-leaks-online

Comment: While using leaks as a source is definitively not a good way to answer a question, you *are* correct.

Comment: That's extremely inconvenient for developers. I'm looking to develop an application, but my Windows 7 machine is already setup and configured with VS2012/2010 and the myriad of other applications and settings required. It's too much risk to switch operating systems at this stage...

Answer (score 6):

To use the solution from @Milkman you need to do the following:

1. Download the full Windows Phone 8 SDK using the `/layout` command-line switch of the `WPexpress_full.exe`.
2. Unzip the provided archive to the target folder replacing already existing files.
3. Go on...

Confirmed that WP8 projects at least open and build in the VS2012.

Answer (score 3):

Don't think there is anything official on that yet. But first messages are that only Windows 8 will be supported.

Also check out this i.e.: http://www.wpcentral.com/windows-phone-8-sdk-preview-release-leaks-online