# How to deploy Windows Phone 7 app, to Windows Phone 8 phone?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-8

The title pretty much sums it up. I've written a Windows Phone 7 application and now I want to deploy it to a Windows Phone 8 device (HTC Windows Phone 8X). I have registered and unlocked this phone for development.

When I plug in the phone via USB and I want to deploy to it using Visual Studio 2010 it keeps on stating that a deployment error occurred as Zune wasn't started up. Windows Phone 8 phones now don't use zune though.

How can I get around this so that I can deploy the WP7 app to the phone?

Comment: Are you sure that it's possible? This suggests that it isn't http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8923508/building-windows-8-metro-app-on-windows-7-with-visual-studio-2010

Comment: While that refers to Windows 8 apps and not Windows Phone 8, the premise still holds true. It's not possible.

Comment: @Kevin Brydon - I have heard though that Windows 8 CAN run Windows 7 apps? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13724852/are-windows-phone-7-apps-compatible-on-windows-phone-8-devices

Comment: Just as a possible solution (very inconvenient): publish the app as beta to the market; you'll be able to install it on the wp8 device then

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't deploy to a Windows Phone 8 device without the Windows Phone 8 SDK, which requires Visual Studio 2012, which also requires Windows 8. So without upgrading, you can't do it.

Comment: I have heard though that Windows 8 CAN run Windows 7 apps? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13724852/are-windows-phone-7-apps-compatible-on-windows-phone-8-devices So when you mean upgrading, you mean not upgrading the app, but upgrading my version of visual studio?

Comment: Yes, if you read what I wrote, you need the WP8 SDK AND VS 2012 AND Windows 8. Windows Phone 8 devices will run WP7 apps that they download from the store (mostly), but if you want to run a development WP7 app on a WP8 device you need ALL the prerequisites above.

Comment: Also please don't confuse Windows 8/7 with Windows Phone 8/7.

Comment: Additionally, thinking back to when I installed the SDK, I believe you'll need the Windows 8 PRO upgrade in order to run the emulator.

Comment: @anothershrubery - Thank you very much, I installed The Windows 8 PRO upgrade on my PC, along with Visual Studio 2012 and the Windows 8 SDK. I then opened my WP7 project in VS2012, and ran the emulator. It worked both on the emulator and my actual Windows 8 Device.

Answer (score 2):

Hard to believe, but it's really possible.
I deployed WP7.1 application to the Windows Phone 8 device (HTC 8X) from Windows7 x64 machine:

1. Install WindowsPhone8SDK (solved on stackoverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11719142/will-windows-phone-8-sdk-run-on-windows-7), detailed instruction [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13507616/how-to-install-windows-phone-8-sdk-on-windows-7), don't forget to aggree with numerous error and warnings)
2. Register and unlock your device by PhoneReg.exe tool ("...\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v8.0\Tools\Phone Registration\PhoneReg.exe")
3. Build your app in VS2010 (I haven't figured out how to deploy the app from VS, this doesn't work)
4. Deploy the app by XapDeploy.exe tool ("...\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v8.0\Tools\XAP Deployment\XapDeploy.exe"). Select the "Device" and point to the directory with *.xap file (...\AppName\Bin\Debug)